# Executing query stuck when xp_cmdshell call FTP_script_txt file

Tags: sql-server, ftp

I'm create stored prcedure to transfer a file from my local system to a FTP server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BackupAndTransferViaFTP
    @ftpServer VARCHAR(255),
    @ftpUsername VARCHAR(255),
    @ftpPassword VARCHAR(255),
    @databaseName NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        -- Turn on 'xp_cmdshell'
        EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
        RECONFIGURE;
        EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
        RECONFIGURE;

        DECLARE @localBackupPath NVARCHAR(255)
        SET @localBackupPath = 'D:\Thon\Backup\' + @databaseName + 'Backup.bak';

        DECLARE @zipBackupPath NVARCHAR(255)
        SET @zipBackupPath = 'D:\Thon\Backup\' + @databaseName + 'Backup.zip';

        DECLARE @backupCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
        SET @backupCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@databaseName) + ' TO DISK = ''' + @localBackupPath + '''';
        EXEC sp_executesql @backupCommand;

        DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000);
        SET @cmd = 'powershell.exe Compress-Archive -Path "' + @localBackupPath + '" -DestinationPath "' + 'D:\Thon\Backup\' + @databaseName + 'Backup.zip"';
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT;

        DECLARE @delBackupfile NVARCHAR(1000);
        SET @delBackupfile = 'DEL ' + @localBackupPath ;
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @delBackupfile, NO_OUTPUT;

---FTP---------------------------------------------------------
        DECLARE @ftpScriptFilePath NVARCHAR(255)
        SET @ftpScriptFilePath = 'D:\Thon\Backup\' + @databaseName + 'Backup_FTP_Script.txt';

        select @ftpserver = replace(replace(replace(@ftpserver, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
        select @ftpUsername = replace(replace(replace(@ftpUsername, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
        select @ftpPassword = replace(replace(replace(@ftpPassword, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
        select @zipBackupPath = replace(replace(replace(@zipBackupPath, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')

        DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(2000)
        SET @Command = 'ECHO open ' + @ftpserver + '>' + @ftpScriptFilePath + '&'
            + 'ECHO ' + @ftpUsername + '>>' + @ftpScriptFilePath + '&'
            + 'ECHO ' + @ftpPassword + '>>' + @ftpScriptFilePath + '&'
            + 'ECHO prompt ' + '>>' + @ftpScriptFilePath + '&'
            + 'ECHO binary ' + '>>' + @ftpScriptFilePath + '&'
            + 'ECHO put ' + @zipBackupPath + '>>' + @ftpScriptFilePath + '&'
            + 'ECHO quit' + '>>' + @ftpScriptFilePath;
        // Wrie to file script
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command, NO_OUTPUT;
 
        // Run FTP Command
        DECLARE @ftpCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
        SET @ftpCommand = 'ftp -s:"' + @ftpScriptFilePath + '"';
        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @ftpCommand;

        -- Turn off 'xp_cmdshell'
        EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
        RECONFIGURE;
        EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
        RECONFIGURE;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH;
END;
```

File script:

```
open "abc.com"
"user"
"password"
prompt
binary
put "D:\Thon\Backup\hBackup.zip"
quit
```

When I run it, the query is executing a long time and hangs, and I cannot cancel, but if `@Command` do not have line `+ 'ECHO put ' + @zipBackupPath + '>>' + @ftpScriptFilePath + '&'`, it will run just fine.

I already ran `@ftpCommand` on the command prompt and it runs fine.

I wish to know what problem with my query. Why the query hangs.

[Stored procedure to move a file from sql server to an ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689858/moving-files-from-one-sql-server-to-another-through-ftp-by-using-a-stored-proced)
I try this but the query still executing a long time and hangs, can not cancel.
I use Task Manager find and end task `ftp.exe File Transfer Program` the query will stop.

Comment: Why are you doing this from SQL Server in the first place ? You can do this easily from command prompt or power shell

Comment: Well, if you execute the same command with the same script file from a Command Prompt... does it pause and prompt you for something on the console?

Comment: The ECHO put line is the only one with `@zipBackupPath` - maybe check that to ensure it is correct?

Comment: Maybe zippath contains spaces or other chars which makes the command do something else

Comment: - I creating stored procedure BackupAndTransfer file to another server - Squirrel

- When i use cmd, it work very well - AlwaysLearning

Comment: The variables ftpUsername, ftpPassword and zipBackupPath are not declared or initialized.

Comment: Thank you, but this is just a 1 part of my code, should I post full? - Ahmed Saeed

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what is problem but i use Powershell and work.

Full code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BackupAndTransferViaFTPPowershell
    @ftpServer VARCHAR(255),
    @ftpUsername VARCHAR(255),
    @ftpPassword VARCHAR(255),
    @databaseName NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        -- Enable 'xp_cmdshell'
        EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
        RECONFIGURE;
        EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
        RECONFIGURE;

        -- Specify the folder path for storing the backup file
        DECLARE @localFolderPath NVARCHAR(255)
        SET @localFolderPath = 'D:\Backup';

        -- Check if the folder exists
        DECLARE @folderExists INT;
        EXEC xp_fileexist @localFolderPath, @folderExists OUTPUT;
        
        -- If the folder does not exist, create a new folder
        IF @folderExists = 0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @cmdCheckExist NVARCHAR(255)
            SET @cmdCheckExist = 'mkdir ' + @localFolderPath;
            EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmdCheckExist, NO_OUTPUT;
        END

        -- Check if the database exists
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @databaseName)
        BEGIN
            -- If the database does not exist, print a message or handle the error as needed
            PRINT 'Database ' + @databaseName + ' does not exist';
            RETURN;
        END

        -- Specify the path for the backup.bak file
        DECLARE @localBackupPath NVARCHAR(255)
        SET @localBackupPath = @localFolderPath +'\'+ @databaseName + '.bak';

        -- Specify the path for the compressed backup.zip file
        DECLARE @zipBackupPath NVARCHAR(255)
        SET @zipBackupPath = @localFolderPath +'\'+ @databaseName + '.zip';

        -- Initialize the database backup command
        DECLARE @backupCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
        SET @backupCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@databaseName) + ' TO DISK = ''' + @localBackupPath + '''';
        -- Execute the database backup command
        EXEC sp_executesql @backupCommand;

        -- Use PowerShell to compress the backup file
        DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000);
        SET @cmd = 'powershell.exe Compress-Archive -Path "' + @localBackupPath + '" -DestinationPath "' + @localFolderPath +'\'+ @databaseName + '.zip"';
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT;

        -- Delete the original backup.bak file after compression
        DECLARE @delBackupfile NVARCHAR(1000);
        SET @delBackupfile = 'DEL ' + @localBackupPath ;
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @delBackupfile, NO_OUTPUT;

        -- FTP Section -------------------------------------
        -- Specify the path for the PowerShell FTP script file
        DECLARE @powershellFtpScriptFilePath NVARCHAR(255)
        SET @powershellFtpScriptFilePath = @localFolderPath +'\'+ @databaseName + '_FTP_Script.ps1';
        
        -- Create content for the PowerShell FTP script file
        DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(2000)
        SET @Command = N'ECHO # FTP Information' + '>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $ftpServer = "' + @ftpServer + '"' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&' -- FTP Server name
                    + 'ECHO $ftpUsername = "' + @ftpUsername + '"' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&' -- FTP username
                    + 'ECHO $ftpPassword = "' + @ftpPassword + '"' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&' -- FTP password
                    + 'ECHO $remotePath = ""' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&' -- FTP server drive to transfer to
                    + 'ECHO $localFilePath = "' + @zipBackupPath + '"' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&' -- Source file
                    + 'ECHO.' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO # Create FTP object ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $ftp = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("ftp://$ftpServer$remotePath/$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($localFilePath))") ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $ftp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ftpUsername, $ftpPassword) ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO.' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO # Read data from local file' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($localFilePath) ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO.' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO # Write data to FTP server' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $requestStream = $ftp.GetRequestStream() ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $requestStream.Write($fileContent, 0, $fileContent.Length) ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $requestStream.Close() ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO.' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO # Close FTP object' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $response = $ftp.GetResponse() ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'
                    + 'ECHO $response.Close() ' +'>>'+ @powershellFtpScriptFilePath + '&'

        -- Write content to the PowerShell FTP script file
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command, NO_OUTPUT;
        
        -- Execute the PowerShell script for FTP transfer
        DECLARE @powershellCommand NVARCHAR(1000);
        SET @powershellCommand = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "'+@powershellFtpScriptFilePath+'"';
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @powershellCommand;      

        -- Delete the compressed backup file after transfer
        DECLARE @delZipBackupfile NVARCHAR(1000);
        SET @delZipBackupfile = 'DEL ' + @zipBackupPath ;
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @delZipBackupfile, NO_OUTPUT;

        -- Disable 'xp_cmdshell'
        EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
        RECONFIGURE;
        EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
        RECONFIGURE;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Handle errors here
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH;
END;
```

Output file script:

```
$ftpServer = "ftpserver"
$ftpUsername = "Username"
$ftpPassword = "Password"
$remotePath = ""  

$localFilePath = "D:\hBackup.zip"

$ftp = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("ftp://$ftpServer$remotePath/$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($localFilePath))")
$ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
$ftp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ftpUsername, $ftpPassword)

$fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($localFilePath)

$requestStream = $ftp.GetRequestStream()
$requestStream.Write($fileContent, 0, $fileContent.Length)
$requestStream.Close()

$response = $ftp.GetResponse()
$response.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**